# Create DB2 iSeries/AS 400 User with minimum roles and privileges to load and remove external jar

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

We are trying to create a DB2 AS400 user with minimum roles and privileges who can load and remove external jar. We have created a user with special authorities SPCAUT like *AUDIT, *IOSYSCFG, *JOBCTL, *SAVSYS, *SERVICE, *SPLCTL but user is not able to load/remove jar and getting below error:

**SQL Error [42501]: [SQL0551] Not authorized to object SQLLib/Function/jar/user/xyz.jar in *N type *N.****

A user with special authority *ALLOBJ is able to load external jar with

`Call SQLJ.DB2_INSTALL_JAR(?, ?, ?)`.
*ALLOBJ authority grants other DML rights too to all user defined schema which is not required in our case. Kindly help with minimum roles and privileges who can load and remove jar.

P.S, Control language Command to create operating system level user:

`CRTUSRPRF   USRPRF(<user_name>)  PASSWORD(<password>)  SPCAUT(*ALLOBJ)`

Comment: All needed authorities are descrided [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzaha/sqljinst.htm)

Comment: Administrative authority means `CHGFCNUSG FCNID(QIBM_DB_SQLADM) USER(<user_name>) USAGE(*ALLOWED)` gives authority

Comment: After executing the change function usage command for function id 'QIBM_DB_SQLADM' and 'QIBM_DB_SECADM', getting same error. Could you please share command for loading and removing jar by normal user.